# Open Cover filters how to avoid test assembly files from code coverage

Tags: code-coverage, opencover

I have gone through the Opencover wiki documentation and tried a lot to figure out what would be the filter criteria for not to include test assembly as part of code coverage. Here is the problem

for eg I have many assemblies starts with sample name like sample.submodule.assembly1.dll, sample.submodule.assembly2.dll, my tests assembly also starts with sample like sample.submodule.tests.dll, here I applied the filter criteria for openCover

1.`-filter: "+[sample*]* -[*tests]*"`
    it didn't work, not generating report file.

2. `-filter: "+[sample*]* -[sample.submodule.tests]*"` didn't work, not generating report file,
3. `-filter: "+[sample*]* -[*]*tests*"` didn't work, not generating report file too,

can somebody please advise what can be the filter criteria here to exclude all the test files from code coverage

Answer (score 7):

First run [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) without any filters.

Now you can look at the XML report produced (or you can use [ReportGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportGenerator/) to turn it into HTML) and identify assemblies/modules that you wish to exclude.

now you can apply filters using the [filter switch](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/wiki/Usage#understanding-filters) e.g.

```
-filter:"+[*]* -[*.tests]* -[*.Tests]*"
```

NOTE: no space between `:` and first `"`

or

```
"-filter:+[*]* -[*.tests]* -[*.Tests]*"
```

Comment: Running OpenCover using a Powershell script in Jenkins, the first example with the `-filter:"filter filter"` format doesn't work with multiple filters, while the second example with the `"-filter:filter filter"` format works perfectly!

Comment: I am running into a similar problem. I have a large repository with different test projects that have different naming conventions. The only thing they all have in common is that they contain the term `Test` while no app projects have this. However, we do have a business object called a `Test` and so some app classes have the term `Test` in their name. Filtering out assemblies like `-[*Test*]` does not seem to be working, in fact it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about writing unit test using visual studio nunit adaptor then you have open cover UI visual studio extension available for all such purpose. it is wonderful.

Step 1) Install open cover from latest relese build https://github.com/opencover/opencover/releases
Step 2) Usuall it will install C:\Users\goma1940\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover (%localappdata%\Apps\OpenCover)
Steo 3) Install VS Extn from gallery https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6950a046-8919-4935-8542-c6f37956f688 
Step 4) you have open cover test explorer and open cover coverage result pane as below…